# Empty AWS S3 bucket of arbitrary cardinality with NodeJS & TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My [removeObjects](https://gitlab.com/tom.davidson/s3nuke/blob/master/src/utils.ts#L7) function has me stummped.The function  is suppose to syncronoulsy get a list of objects in an S3 bucket then asyncronously removes the objects. Repeat if the list was truncated, until the there are no more objects to remove. (AWS doesn't provide the total count of objects in the bucket and listObjects pages the results.)

What am I doing wrong / why doesn't my function work? The solution should exploit single thread and async nature of JS. For the bounty I am hoping for an answer specific to the module. The [git repo](https://gitlab.com/tom.davidson/s3nuke) is public if you want to see the entire module.

```
export function removeObjects(params: IS3NukeRequest): Promise<S3.Types.DeleteObjectsOutput> {

  const requests: Array<Promise<S3.Types.DeleteObjectsOutput>> = [];
  let isMore;

  do {
    listObjectsSync(params)
      .then((objectList: S3.Types.ListObjectsV2Output) => {
        isMore = objectList.ContinuationToken = objectList.IsTruncated ? objectList.NextContinuationToken : null;
        requests.push(params.Client.deleteObjects(listObjectsV2Output2deleteObjectsRequest(objectList)).promise());
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => { Promise.reject(err); });
  } while (isMore);

  return Promise.all(requests);
}

export async function listObjectsSync(params: IS3NukeRequest): Promise<S3.Types.ListObjectsV2Output> {
  try {
    return await params.Client.listObjectsV2(s3nukeRequest2listObjectsRequest(params)).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `lostObjectsSync`is not synchronous as you can't make a sync function from an async one. What is the problem that happens?

Comment: I maybe using async and await incorrectly, but it is a reality. "The await operator is used to wait for a Promise returned by an async function." - MSDN

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `listObjectsSync` function returns a `Promise`, so you need to treat it as an async function and can't just use a loop with it. What you need to do is to create a chain of promises while your `isMore` is true, I've done it using a recursive approach (I'm not pro in TS, so please check the code before using it). I also haven't tried the code live, but logically it should work :)

```
 const requests: Array<Promise<S3.Types.DeleteObjectsOutput>> = [];
  function recursive(recursiveParams) {
    return listObjectsSync(recursiveParams).then((objectList: S3.Types.ListObjectsV2Output) => {
        let isMore = objectList.ContinuationToken = objectList.IsTruncated ? objectList.NextContinuationToken : null;
                      requests.push(params.Client.deleteObjects(listObjectsV2Output2deleteObjectsRequest(objectList)).promise());
        if (isMore) {
          //do we need to change params here?
          return recursive(recursiveParams)
        }
        //this is not necessary, just to indicate that we get out of the loop
        return true;    
      });
  }

  return recursive(params).then(() => {
     //we will have all requests here
     return Promise.all(requests);
  });
```

Comment: Coming from sync languages I default to a recursive solution for this kind of thing too. While Im a be of a js newbie it just seems like anti-pattern for js. Before going back to that, are you familiar with with async & await? My [s3objectgenerator](https://gitlab.com/tom.davidson/s3objectgenerator/blob/master/src/s3-object-generator.ts) seems to work just fine (unless my spec is broken too). Since I am using a transpiler I want to take advantage for recent ecma spec.

Comment: @Tom your `generate` function from the file you provided doesn't have any extra async calls inside, you just get promises and then wait for all of them, so it's working correctly. For the function that you have trouble with you have a call to a promise inside the function in a loop, so you need to wait for the results first and then do whatever you're doing. You can also transform the recursion into a loop with `await`, it will do the same job. As or the anti-pattern, you can use a for loop or convert the code to using `await`. Btw, the `catch` is not needed, so I've removed it

Comment: I do not want to award the bounty because the answer did not explain why the es7/typescript function with async and await does not work which is clearly part of the question.

Comment: It doesn't resolve because `Promise.all` is executed before all requests are pushed to the array. If you debug the function, you will see that it's either empty or doesn't have all requests inside. This happens because you perform async operations in the `while` loop. My code fixes that by calling the `Promise.all` after all requests have been pushed to the array by building a chain of promises